# Hook into `require` in Webpack at runtime

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

In Node.js there's a few modules for hooking into `require`:

- https://github.com/opbeat/require-in-the-middle
- https://github.com/catamphetamine/require-hacker

Wondering if it's possible to do this in Webpack at runtime, not with a precompiled plugin.

Comment: To what end? What's the use case that's not covered by a [webpack loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/)?

Comment: I would like to get a list of the required modules as they are required.

Comment: Any updates? I would have the same question. I need the required chunk filename before it starts downloading.

Comment: I'm also interested into this question.